# Limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0^{+}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital, substitution

Find $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[5]{x}-\sqrt[7]{x}}$$ I tried to apply l'hospital's rule but it didn't work . Multiplying by conjugates also didn't help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint.

Let $x=t^{210}$.

Hence, we need to calculate $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{t^{105}-t^{70}}{t^{42}-t^{30}},$$ which is $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{t^{70}\left(t^{35}-1\right)}{t^{30}\left(t^{12}-1\right)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{t^{40}\left(t^{35}-1\right)}{t^{12}-1}=\frac{0(0-1)}{0-1}=0.$$

Comment: Nice answer ! Can you help me about when we can neglect some terms like $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt[5]{x}$ here ?

Comment: They are $t^{105}$ and $t^{42}$ here.

Comment: My mean is omitting $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt[5]{x}$ at first .

Comment: @S.H.W if $x\rightarrow0^+$ you can neglect something, but I think here it's better to end the calculating of the limit. I added something. See now.

Comment: Another example that I have seen is writing $\sqrt[3]{x}$ instead of $x^4 + x^3 + \sqrt[3]{x}$ when $x \to 0$ . I think it would be useful in many questions but isn't mathematically right . This is just a guess .

Comment: In this case we can neglect  $x^4$ and $x^3$.

Comment: Okay but how you would be sure that it doesn't affect limit ?

Comment: I think because $\frac{1}{2}>\max\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{7}\}$ and  $\frac{1}{3}>\max\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{7}\}$ then our limit is equal to $0$. But we can see it easier after substitution $x=t^{210}.$

Comment: @S.H.W the general idea in this way is to change $x$ to a different variable so that all the fractions will become integers, you can easily find this: consider the limit $\lim{x\to0}\frac{a_0x^\frac{1}{m_0}+a_1x^\frac{1}{m_1}+\cdots+a_kx^\frac{1}{m_k}}{b_0x^\frac{1}{n_0}+b_1x^\frac{1}{n_1}+\cdots+b_kx^\frac{1}{n_k}}$, in this case you say $x=t^{m_0\cdot m_1\cdot\cdots\cdot m_k\cdot n_0\cdot n_1\cdot\cdots\cdot n_k}$. in your case you have $a_0=1,a_1=-1,b_0=1,b_1=-1,m_0=2,m_1=3,n_0=5,n_1=7$ so you get $x=t^{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}=t^{210}$

Comment: @Holo How you can represent $x^4 + x^3 + \sqrt[3]{x}$ as that formula ?

Comment: Let $x-t^3$. Hence, our expression it's $t^{12}+t^{9}+t,$ which for $t\rightarrow0$ is acting like $t$.

Comment: @S.H.W although i wrote $\frac{1}{m_i}$ and $\frac{1}{n_i}$ it is really should be $\frac{p_i}{n_i\lor m_i}$, so in the case of $4$ you can look at this as $\frac{4}{1}$ and likewise the $3$, so when thinking about what degree should $t$ be you can ignore integers, and if you have something in the form of $\frac{7}{9}$ for example you ignore the $7$ and look only on the $9$, you can see that Michael did the same, ignore the $3$ and $4$ and only look at the $\frac13$

Comment: so to summary: when you have $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a_0x^\frac{p_0}{m_0}+a_1x^\frac{p_1}{m_1}+\cdots+a_kx^\frac{p_k}{m_k}}{b_0x^\frac{q_0}{n_0}+b_1x^\frac{q_1}{n_1}+\cdots+b_kx^\frac{q_k}{n_k}}$$you choose $$x=t^{m_0\cdot m_1\cdot\cdots\cdot m_k\cdot n_0\cdot n_1\cdot\cdots\cdot n_k}$$

Comment: btw, in the denominator and numerator you there should be a constant: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a+a_0x^\frac{p_0}{m_0}+a_1x^\frac{p_1}{m_1}+\cdots+a_kx^\frac{p_k}{m_k}}{b+b_0x^\frac{q_0}{n_0}+b_1x^\frac{q_1}{n_1}+\cdots+b_kx^\frac{q_k}{n_k}}$

Comment: @Holo Sorry , can you apply this for $x^4 + x^3 + \sqrt[3]{x}$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W in the case of $x^4 + x^3 + \sqrt[3]{x}=x^4 + x^3 + x^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{x^4 + x^3 + x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{1}=\frac{x^\frac41 + x^\frac31 + x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{1}$, so $b=1$ and $b_n=0$ for all $n$, and $a=0,a_0=1,a_1=1,a_2=1$ and $a_n=0$ for all $n>2$ and $p_0=4,p_1=3,p_2=1$ and $m_0=1,m_1=1,m_2=3$(we ignore all the elements where $b_i=0$ or $a_i=0$), so we set $x=t^{1\cdot1\cdot3}=t^3$. so we get $\boxed{x^4+x^3+x^\frac13=t^{12}+t^9+t}$

Comment: @Holo Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{1/2}-x^{1/3}}{x^{1/5}-x^{1/7}}
=x^{4/21}\frac{x^{1/6}-1}{x^{2/35}-1}.$$
Each term here has a nice limit as $x\to0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

When going to zero, the smallest exponents dominate and your expression is asymptotic to $x^{1/3-1/7}$, hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: I have seen the same argument many times . How you can prove it ?

Comment: @S.H.W: see the answer by user "Lord Shark the Unknown" for the proof.

Comment: $x^a+x^b=x^a(1+x^{a-b})$ clearly tends to $x^a$ for $a>b$.